# Keeping the same name of the table in the entites folder in symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, database, entity-framework, symfony

I currently developing a book review system using symfony2, I have successfully created the database table on a localhost as following:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM BookReview;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Review     | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rating     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AppUser_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Book_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The name of this table is BookReview, both the B and R are capital letters, but When using the `doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle` to create entities for my project, the letter R in the name of the table "BooKReview" becomes  small letter, and the name of entitie becomes  "Bookreview" instead Of "BooKReview". is there any way of keeping the name of the table exactly the same.

```
~/Desktop/test222/BRS$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import  AppBundle
Importing mapping information from "default" entity manager
  > writing /home/sta177/Desktop/test222/BRS/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Bookreview.orm.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define tableName explicit in yml:

```
BookReview:
  type: entity
  table: BookReview
```

So I guest that you can do this same in XML
I Don;t know exact structure

Comment: In this case You have you ranswer? :)